# How do I use Bootstrap Icons in C# Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I'm making a Blazor WebAssembly website in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and I'm having some trouble getting the bootstrap icons to show up on the navmenu. I installed the icons via npm and copied the bootstrap folder to my wwwroot in the project viewer.

My code for the navmenu item looks like this:

```
<div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Spotify">
                <span class="bi bi-spotify" aria-hidden="true"></span> Spotify
            </NavLink>
    </div>
```

The default for the span class was `span class="oi oi-plus"` and it ran fine and that icon showed up, but when I run the program with the new span class code as above, the icon doesn't show up on next to the text or anywhere at all.

Comment: I wrote this a few weeks ago. https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorBootstrapIcons/tree/master/BlazorBootstrapIcons#blazor-components-for-bootstrap-icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only copy bootstrap-icons.svg from bootstraps [repo](https://github.com/twbs/icons/blob/main/bootstrap-icons.svg). Put this in a folder within your `wwwroot` folder.

For example to create `emoji-smile-fill` use.

```
<svg class="bi" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" >
    <use href="{folder-to-resource}/bootstrap-icons.svg#emoji-smile-fill"></use>
</svg>
```